# Word for 'one who steals books'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the name of the person who steals books?
Can you please tell me what is the word for it?

Comment: Probably the more common expression is *"book thief*" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=biblioklept%2Cbook+stealer%2Cbook+thief&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbiblioklept%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbook%20thief%3B%2Cc0, also thanks to the novel and the recent movie https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_Thief

Comment: .A tome raider.

Comment: I usually call the people who steal my books "friends". Are you talking about people who don't return books you loan them, or someone who, for instance, shoplifts bestsellers to take to a used book shop?

Comment: @sumelic - I didn't post it as an answer because OP  is asking for a single word, but  I think it is the expression normally used.

Comment: @Josh61: I edited the tags on this question recently for just this reason-- the "single word requests" tag is not actually from the OP, but from a later editor. It's not completely clear yet if the OP wants a single word, or phrases as well. (While the question does say "the word for it", that might encompass phrases.)

Answer (score 12):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biblioklept):

> **biblioklept** (plural biblioklepts)
>
> A person who steals books

**E.g.**

> *But the extreme is found in covetousness, and the covetous man who is in the extreme state of bookloving, is the **biblioklept**, or
>   **bookstealer**.*

[Merriam-webster.com]

Comment: I was just going to add the attribution (as is required), but found that the M-W article was inaccessible. I switched to the equivalent definition from Wiktionary. I assume the example is from the not generally accessible M-W article.

Comment: You might also indicate that this word is rare and not commonly heard.

Comment: @sumelic Perhaps rare, perhaps not commonly heard, but if this word didn't already exist, I'd have created it. The roots are readily understandable to a bibliophile.

Answer (score 5):

A more common expression is ***book thief*** probably thanks to the [novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_Thief) and recent [movie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_Thief_(film)) with the same name.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=biblioklept%2Cbook%20stealer%2Cbook%20thief&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbiblioklept%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbook%20thief%3B%2Cc0): *biblioklept vs book stealer vs book thief*.